# Prevent legs from coming out of socks

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I imported makehuman model with stockings to Blender, cut the stockings and made socks out of them. My problem is that the legs are coming out of the socks in some of the animation frames.

For now, I am making the socks really large so the knee would not stick out, but this is not the solution I wish to move forward with.

I posted the picture showing the problem and the .blend file here:
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?304725-Legs-coming-out-of-socks

Comment: I had a similar issue see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/how-should-clothes-be-modified-to-fit-a-character-model

Comment: I was going to try shrink wrap modifier but only scaling the socks (duplicated from mesh of lower legs) solved the problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are four main solutions of varying complexity... you may choose to do all three:

1. Put a *lot* of love into weight painting on both the leg and the sock so you don't get intersections on deformation.
2. Use a mesh deform modifier as part of your rig. If the leg and the sock are both deformed by the mesh deform modifier, there's less likelihood that you'll have intersections.
3. Use corrective shape keys... if the intersection happens reliably and predictably as the knee bends, you can make a shape key that fixes the intersection. You can then drive the influence of that shape key using the knee's rotation.
4. Put the sock and the leg on different render layers and make sure the sock layer is always over the leg layer. This may require some clever masking for the back of the, but it's doable.

Comment: Looks like ShrinkWrap modifier is another alternative. Let me try the solutions.

Comment: Interestingly, I solved the problem by deleting the old socks, duplicating the mesh of lower feet and scaling up it a little bit! Didn't know it would be that simple :-)

Comment: That solution works because you're coming from MakeHuman and the weight painting is already done... you're taking advantage of that (and rightly so). However, had your model come in without a rig or any pre-assigned weights, that solution may not work as well.

Comment: Yeah. Since I used the mesh of the body itself, the weight paint was already there.