# How can I thicken mesh hair?

Tags: modeling, mesh

Is there anyway of making some hair I modelled thicker because what I currently have is too thin and I want it to be a bit thicker.

Comment: Please give example pictures so we know what we are dealing with.

Comment: "the" anime hair? Is it some kind of primitive?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are modeling the hair and going for an anime style. The [*Solidify*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html#solidify-modifier) modifier should do this quite well. It might seem subtle but you will get the depth you want.

[image]

Flat mesh hair.

[image]

Mesh hair with solidify modifier.

After using the modifier, you can apply it and tweak the mesh even further to get better results. Using the modifier is better than just extruding and tweaking as it will do this evenly for your entire mesh.

You can get some unique styles as well if you smooth the hair with a subsurf modifier and play with the settings.

[image]

Comment: this actually kind of helped me in a way im still new to blender so please excuse me if i don't understand the stuff you describe to me as yet.i can give you an example of the hair im trying to gethttp://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/53566

Comment: @tokenten You should be able to achieve something similar using what I have outlined in my answer. An exact, complete walkthrough would take too long to write and tutorials shouldn't be given as answers either.

Comment: I did indeed now with the clothes it much much easier to make it fit on my model instead of playing tug of war with it.and the hair is perfect

Comment: @tokenten If you intend to continue using this site and want to get access to more features, you might want to consider fully registering your account ;) and see this answer, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/how-should-clothes-be-modified-to-fit-a-character-model.