# Fitting clothes to character model with python

Tags: python, scripting

I want to add different clothes to imported character models with python. 
I read a similar question about cloth-modification to fit a character model [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/how-should-clothes-be-modified-to-fit-a-character-model), but it seems this modifier can't be used with blender python. Is there any way where I can automatically add locally stored clothes-objects to imported character models and make them fitting well via python? I am using MH for the character modelling, but it seems adding clothes can't be scripted there, so I guess blender is where this step needs to be done.

Comment: Please elaborate why you think that the you cannot use modifiers within blender python. Do you have example code that does not work?

Answer (score 2):

Well, i don't know what modifiers you mean, but a common way is to create the Basic shape of the cloth around the Body.
After that's done you add a subsurface and a shrinkwrap mod. Now switch to edit-mode and play around with the modell untill most parts of the cloth fit to the Surface of the character. Now you add a solidify mod. Now you should have a simple cloth-part fitting onto your mesh.
For more a more detailed explanation check this out:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljMePAmmxx4

Hope I can help you...

Comment: Thank you a lot for this answer K.Ueltzen. This is how I want to do it, but in my case I want a script that does exactly these things. There seems to be a feature that tracks what you do and you can create a script from it, but that doesn't seem to work that well. So still I am looking for some way to get this workflow automated in a python script.

Comment: If the add on you have doesn't work you should contact the developer.