# Is there a way to proportional edit one object while preventing it from intersecting itself and other objects?

Tags: modeling

I want to manipulate a cloth model around a character model but some parts of it go into the character model and itself while editing the mesh.

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! Some more information would be useful here. There are a bunch of possible solutions (cloth simulation, snapping, shrinkwrap, etc.) but it's hard to say what to suggest. Editing your question to include an image of the exact situation, or even a similar, simplified one would be helpful. Otherwise a more detailed description would suffice. Are you trying to make a shirt? A cape? What have you tried so far? That kind of thing.

Comment: Also, check out this question here. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/how-should-clothes-be-modified-to-fit-a-character-model?rq=1